# How to get subject, content, etc fetched via Net::IMAP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, imap

I'm facing trouble decoding messages fetched through ruby's `Net::IMAP`, here's what I've tried in console

```
imap = Net::IMAP.new(‘imap.gmail.com’,993,true)
imap.login(“my@gmail.com”, “mypassword”)
imap.select(‘INBOX’)

msgs = []

imap.uid_search(["NOT", "DELETED"]).each do |uid|
  msgs << imap.uid_fetch(uid, ['RFC822']).first.attr['RFC822'].to_s
end
```

Now when I'm doing `msgs.first` I'm getting this

```
"Return-Path: <my@gmail.com>\r\n
Received: from 192.168.10.191:3000 ([111.93.167.67])\r\n       
 by mx.google.com with ESMTPSA id kz4sm35619700pbc.39.1969.12.31.16.00.00\r\n 
(version=TLSv1.1 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA bits=128/128);\r\n
Thu, 05 Sep 2013 06:18:24 -0700 (PDT)\r\n
Date: Thu, 05 Sep 2013 18:48:18 +0530\r\n
From: my@gmail.com\r\n
Reply-To: please-change-me-at-config-initializers-devise@example.com\r\n
To: admin@example.com\r\n
Message-ID: <5228849ab79c5_4b57133029c665c4@rajde1.mail>\r\n
Subject: Confirmation instructions\r\n
Mime-Version: 1.0\r\n
Content-Type: text/html;\r\n
charset=UTF-8\r\n
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n
<p>Welcome admin@example.com!</p>\r\n\r\n<p>You can confirm your account email through the link below:</p>\r\n\r\n<p><a href=\"http://192.168.10.191:3000/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=jqFrp48CyqnFDwBKpxBV\">Confirm my account</a></p>\r\n"
```

How to decode this, please help. I'm new to this feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you retrieve `RFC822` you get the whole thing. If you retrieve `BODY.PEEK[HEADER.FIELDS (Subject)]` you'll get just the subject. (There's also an `ENVELOPE` which can be quite handy, it contains Subject, From and a few more, neatly parsed for you.) Fetching the body (I assume that's what you mean by content) is a little more tricky, you need to first retrieve the bodystructure, then retrieve the parts you want, often `BODY.PEEK[1]` or `BODY.PEEK[1.2]` or somesuch.

Answer (score 4):

Try using something like this:

```
body1 = imap.fetch(uid, "RFC822")[0].attr["RFC822"]
mail = Mail.new(body1)
subject = mail.subject
to      = mail.to
```

like that you could take all the value.

Comment: Gr8 you make my day :)